# Snapchat Snap Kit iOS Login Redirect URL not working on Safari

Tags: ios, swift, safari, plist, snapchat

I am implementing iOS login with the [Snapchat Login Kit API](https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/login-kit-ios) and I got most of it working except for when safari is supposed to redirect to the app. I keep getting the screenshot below.

[image: iOS Simulator iPhone 12]

I followed all of the steps in the documentation and I am not sure if this is an unrelated issue?

I have added the following to my info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>MyAppName</string>
<key>SCSDKClientId</key>
    <string>my-snapchat-client-id-here</string>
<key>SCSDKRedirectUrl</key>
    <string>MyAppName://snap-kit/oauth2</string>
<key>SCSDKScopes</key>
<array>
    <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.display_name</string>
    <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.bitmoji.avatar</string>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>snapchat</string>
    <string>bitmoji-sdk</string>
    <string>itms-apps</string>
</array>
```